# Converting a string into double and adding it to a variable

Tags: java

As the title suggests, I came up with this code and I'm not sure why it doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

```
double value = 0;
String input;

input = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();

    if (input.substring(0, 1) == "+") {
        value = value + Double.parseDouble(input.substring(1));
    }
```

Then, I typed the input "+ 25" (without the quotation marks). Also, `.toUpperCase` is there for another line of code; and then, printed the values to see if I got anything wrong.

```
System.out.println( input.substring(0, 1));
System.out.println( Double.parseDouble(input.substring(1)) );
System.out.println( value );
```

first one printed +

second one printed 25.0

and value printed out 0.0

Everything seems to check, why is value still 0.0?

Comment: whats your input string ?

Comment: Your if statement is always failing, so you aren't setting `value`, so it's still 0.

Comment: Use `equals()` to compare values of strings.

Comment: `if (input.substring(0, 1) == "+") {` this will never be true. You need to use String.equals

Comment: @ASP I said it, its + 25

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thanks to all of you!